# How do I create an AWS Access Point Policy, without getting "Error Policy has invalid resource"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using

```
$ aws s3 mb s3://freds-321-pizza
make_bucket: freds-321-pizza
```

to successfully create a bucket.
Using AWS Console

1. create access point, name - freds-access-point
2. check internet box
3. "block all public access" - tried with this on and off
4. ARN - created [arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:************:accesspoint/freds-access-point
5. Submit "Create Access Point"
6. Successfully created access point: freds-access-point

Go back into Access Point and Edit Policy, as follows;

```
{ 
   "Version": "2012-10-17", 
   "Statement": [ 
     { 
       "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:PutObject"], 
       "Effect": "Allow", 
       "Principal": {"AWS": ["*"]}, 
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::freds-321-pizza/*"] 
     } 
   ] 
 }
```

Getting **"Error Policy has invalid resource"**, please help?

Note:
AWS CLI; --doesn't work

`aws s3control get-access-point --name freds-access-point --account-id ************`

Will update when I find the right command.

Comment: Have just tried to create policy with access point as resource and this has worked !!! `arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:************:accesspoint/freds-access-point/object/*` How very interesting that the policy has to access itself...

Answer (score 1):

This is beacause you're giving the S3 Bucket ARN, not the actual resources you want to attach to the policy. Objects within the S3 are the actual resources you look for.

Your Resource should look something like this:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:zone:account_ID:accesspoint/access-point-name/object/*"
```

**/object/**

Hope this was helpful!